# Calculate Process Time Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for some assistance in calculating the time taken between 2 dates.
I have in column "A" item name and each item can have up to 5 completion stages called item status in column "B". Each completion stages has a time/date stamp in column "C".

Question: How do I calculate the time between each stage?

I have tried with =Networkdays but I'm not sure how to add the criterias to the formula?
Criterias: Same item name and the calculation need to be in the right seqence (time between Step 1 and 2, time between step 2 and step 3 etc.)

This is the formula I've tried to use but I am not sure how to add the criterias

=NETWORKDAYS(C2;C3)

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: is the data always sorted like you show?

Comment: @ScottCraner Hmm, really good question - for now, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use when sorted:

```
=IF(A2=A3,NETWORKDAYS(C2,C3),"-")
```

If not sorted.

```
=IF(MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,C:C,">"&C2)>0,NETWORKDAYS(C2,MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,C:C,">"&C2)),"-")
```

Comment: Wow - this is brilliant - I've spent more than 6 hours with out success

Comment: And what if the data is randomly sorted?

Comment: Then it gets a lot more complicated.  We would need to know some assumptions.  Like is it always `Step#` in order as in that is the actual verbiage?  Or are the dates always sequential between the steps.

Comment: The dates are always sequential between the steps

Comment: But I can see that data is randomly sorted - unfortunately I get wrong calculation because of that